# PHP json_encode issue with balckslash

Tags: php

We encountered issue with backslash.

When we json_encode "FBU4061\0258" it becomes FBU40618 with double quotes,

```
$x = "FBU4061\0258";
json_encode($x, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

but with singe quotes it gives the correct value 'FBU4061\0258'.

```
$x = 'FBU4061\0258';
json_encode($x, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

How to eliminate this issue as when we fetch data it comes with double quotes ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), PHP does an escape sequence replacement, and `\0` is the `NUL` byte.

> `\\[0-7]{1,3}` the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation

Such replacement is not performed when using the [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), so you get the expected result.

As per @Quentin words:

> You have to take into account the difference between the source code of a string literal and the value of that string literal once it has been passed through the PHP compiler.

Comment: In other words: You have to take into account the difference between the source code of a string literal and the value of that string literal once it has been passed through the PHP compiler.

Comment: What is the solution guys ?

Comment: @MDeSilva use single quotes.

Comment: How to convert double quotes into single quotes ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you question ... change the source code?